# Delete the highest number of an array

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, max

First I created a random array then I decided to create another array to save the number except the highest. I got the prob when printing the array removed the highest number. I assume the issue when assigning item in b but I can't figure out. Please help :<

```
public static int[] deleteHighestNum(int a[]) {
    int b[] = new int[a.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[j]) {
            b[j++] = a[j];
        }
    }
    return b;
```

Comment: Please add the code you have so far to your question, and explain exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: Please show a complete, runnable example which illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you first create a copy of the array with the .clone() method. This will be the second array you created. then you create an int x or something of this sort and set it equal to 0.

start now by iterating the array. if the number is greater then your int, replace the int.
once it is done, make another loop, that checks each value of your second array and if a number is equal to your int, delete it. done.